# How do I provide a config file (.env) when starting a container?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to install a GUI on Bitcoin Lightning Network Testnet. I have 2 lightning nodes running and connected together. Both in containers.

Now I would like to have a GUI interface to manage my nodes. I used this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/apotdevin/thunderhub

I can start the container and access it on my local computer on port 3000.

My question is how do I configure Thunderhub to connect to my nodes ?

If I follow the instructions on the Thunderhub home page, they refer me to this page:

https://docs.thunderhub.io/setup/#server-accounts

But the instructions are:

```
You can add accounts on the server by adding this parameter to the .env file:
.....
```

How should I proceed from there ? Does it means I must rebuild the image ?
How do I provide a '.env' config file when starting a container

Comment: From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options "--env-file  Read in a file of environment variables"

Comment: How Did you run your thunderhub?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running containers using docker-compose and use "environment" directive.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

From this link above is a good example, see step 5. Also you can create .env file in the same directory as the the docker-compose.yml See examples in this link below.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

If you don't want use docker-compose, you can use --env flag:

```
docker run --env VAR1=value1 --env VAR2=value2 ubuntu env
```

Comment: You can also use --env-file with docker run...